# Avoid raw resource duplicates, but still keep unique references

Tags: android

In an Android project I have several thousand highly dynamic audio files, in multiple languages. Highly dynamic as in they may change from week to week during development. 
Some files are duplicates (within a language), and will have to be in order not to break the logic in the code and for maintanability - but it is a waste of space!

Example (just an example, don't worry about semantics):

```
raw/en/time_rep.mp3 - used as in "one more time"
raw/en/time.mp3 - used as in "it is now time for"

raw/de/time_rep.mp3 - may be translated to "mal"
raw/de/time.mp3 - may be translated to "zeit"
```

So, the word is same in English, and therefore a duplicate, but not in German, therefore, we need two resources.

Ideally in English both R.raw.time_rep and R.raw.time would refer to the same  time.mp3 audio file, but not in German.

For strings and images it is possible to create an AliasResource, but not for raw files.

Any thoughts on how I can create "soft links" to avoid duplicate having raw resources, so that I can still reference R.raw.time_rep and R.raw.time from within the code, with little to no manual changes whenever I get a new batch of updated raw audio files?

NB: Don't worry about identifying the duplicates. I can do this in a batch script while converting and post processing the audio files.

Comment: Why don't you simply use **TTS**? You'd avoid to waste a lot of space and code logic.

Comment: TTS is not good enough for our need. We tried. Wish it was :)

Comment: Did you upgrade the TTS Engine to the latest versions? They are VERY good (tested: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish).

Comment: Korean, Japanese, and Chinese is needed as well.
But to be honest, we haven't, but we are waaaay past that point now :-D
But for the next project I will :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Any thoughts on how I can create "soft links" to avoid duplicate having raw resources, so that I can still reference R.raw.time_rep and R.raw.time from within the code, with little to no manual changes whenever I get a new batch of updated raw audio files?

Just create lookup table (in any form you like: HashMap, database table etc) and then use it to pick right audio file instead of picking it directly like you do now.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of generating a java file with a lookup table. But if there are any alternatives (like AliasResources, but working) I would like to know :-)

Comment: No, there's no Alias Resources because LUT works just fine and is trivial to implement

Comment: Yes, LUT is trivial. Automatically looping through 2500 resources in several languages, mapping these into a LUT and generating a java file, or whatever form, and then change several hundred references around the code, is less trivial - which is why I investigate options before doing so, just in case there was some magic option somewhere I've overlooked.

Comment: I bet my supprt that you'd be already done with writing code to generate all this stuff by now if you had started instead of asking your question here :)

Comment: ...or getting into a fruitless discussion about what would be faster. 
Either way, it's not about which way is faster to implement, it's about making the optimal solution, and preferably learning new things in the process.